# How to extract time from lubridate?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I want to extract a day-, month-, hour- and minute-vector from a vector of the type factor of the format "DD-M-YYYY HH:MM" (e.g. "14-3-2018 00:34").

Using Lubridate, the month and day are retrieved as expected, but when I try to retrieve the hour and the minute, it returns all zero's.

I've tried the following:

```
dataset$Month = month(dataset$msgDateTime)
dataset$Day = day(dataset$msgDateTime)
dataset$Hour = hour(dataset$msgDateTime)
dataset$Minute = minute(dataset$msgDateTime)
```

And so the first two lines yielded the results I wanted, but the last two lines only resulted in zero's.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: First convert it to `datetime` `dataset$msgDateTime <- dmy_hm(dataset$msgDateTime)` and then extract the elements,

Comment: `minute(dmy_hm( "14-3-2018 00:34"))#
[1] 34`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

factor_datetime <- factor("14-3-2018 00:34")

tibble(
  full_datetime = lubridate::dmy_hm(
    factor_datetime,
    quiet = FALSE,
    tz = "UTC",
    locale = Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"),
    truncated = 0
  )) %>%
  mutate(Month = lubridate::month(full_datetime),
         Day = lubridate::day(full_datetime),
         Hour = lubridate::hour(full_datetime),
         Minute = lubridate::minute(full_datetime))

# A tibble: 1 x 5
# full_datetime        Month   Day  Hour Minute
# <dttm>               <dbl> <int> <int>  <int>
# 2018-03-14 00:34:00      3    14     0     34
```